# how to create input (type = text) which accepts values from select option?

Tags: javascript, html

In html we create input box as `input(type='text')` and

```
<select>
 <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
 <option value="saab">Saab</option>
 <option value="opel">Opel</option>
 <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

How do you make a text box, which permits option only from options provided for, either thru (the select tag or otherwise). The idea is that the user can type the input rather than to have to choose from dropdown.

I can use typeahead. But how to confine inputs limited to typeahead options. Thru javascript? Is that the only solution?

Comment: In short you want `Auto Complete` Right :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some great plugins were mentioned, but if you're looking for a more customizable solution, you could easily accomplish this with a few lines of jQuery. The following code will restrict the input to a pre-defined list of words (in this case, the list is defined in the HTML markup, but the list could also be implemented in the JavaScript). You could easily extend this solution to do *exactly* what you want. Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ePSXd/).

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" data-values="Volvo,Saab,Opel,Audi">
```

**JavaScript**

```
$("input").on("keyup", function() {
    var input = $(this).val();
    var values = $(this).data("values").split(",");
    var found = false;
    $(values).each(function(index, value) {
        if (value.toLowerCase().indexOf(input.toLowerCase()) > -1) {
            found = true;
        }
    });
    if (!found) {
        $(this).val($(this).val().slice(0,-1));
    }
});
```

Comment: No problem! Good luck on your project.

Answer (score 5):

Chosen and Select2 are more suitable for this than typeahead:

- [Chosen http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/)
- [Select2 http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/)

Comment: Amazing! Thanks! :) I was actually looking for the select multiple to tag option as well! Cheers

Comment: No problem. I have run into this exact problem before, so I know your pain. :)

Answer (score 0):

you can do this with autocomplete,

```
   var givenoptions = ["Volvo", "Saab", "Opel", "Audi"]
   empty = "";

    $('#selecttext').autocomplete({
autoFocus: true,
source: givenoptions
 }).keyup(function() {
   var isValid = false;
   for (i in givenoptions) {
    if (givenoptions[i].toLowerCase().match(this.value.toLowerCase())) {
        isValid = true;
    }
}
if (!isValid) {
    this.value = empty
} else {
    empty = this.value;
}
});


 <input id="selecttext" />
```